# Custom InitialDirectory C# using app.config

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have the following in my App.config file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <configuration>
      <appSettings>
       <add key="save" value="C:\Test"/>
      </appSettings>
       </configuration>
```

And the following in my Main.cs

```
private void tsSaveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

     sd.Filter = "TIFF Files (*.tif)|*.tif";
     sd.FilterIndex = 1;
     sd.InitialDirectory = 

}
```

I would like to know how I can use the value from the key to set the InitialDirectory. The idea being that Once the app is installed I want users to navigate to app.config file and change this just the once.

Is this a good way or are there better methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the initail directory from web.config key by

```
sd .InitialDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ConfigurationManager:

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
```

In your case:

```
value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["save"];
```